# .Htaccess redirect from file to same file on subdomain with GET?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Current URL:

http://www.example.com/a/pa.php?url=parameter&id=parameter

To:

http://**app**.example.com/pa.php?url=parameter&id=parameter

The subdomain changes and this rule should ONLY apply to the file "pa.php" and to no other files in the folder /a/.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `.htaccess` file under root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^a/pa.php$ http://app.example.com/pa.php [L,R=301]
```